# Is equals() and toHashCode affects vector add() remove() methods behaviour

Tags: java, vector, equals, hashcode

As in the subject: Is equals() affects vector add() remove() methods behaviour.

I have got `Vector<T> v;`

1.Does the `remove()` method will work correct if I will not redefine `equals()` or `hashCode()` function in `type T`?

2.Does the `add()` method will work correct if I will not redefine `equals()` or `hashCode()` function in `type T`?

Comment: `Vector` is deprecated; you should use `ArrayList<T>`.  See the documentation.

Comment: @SLaks - `Vector` is not deprecated. However, `ArrayList` is generally preferred, since the synchronization offered by `Vector` is almost always at the wrong level of granularity.

Comment: Note that you could have found out yourself by reading the javadoc of Vector and its methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you do not define an `equals()` for `T`, `Vector.remove` will use the default `equals()` implementation, which is object identity (`==`).
2. `Vector.add()` does not use `equals()`. It will happily add duplicates.

In either case, `Vector` does not use `hashCode` at all, so the implementation of `hashCode` (or lack thereof) will not affect the operation of `Vector` at all. However, if you redefine `equals()` for your element type, you must redefine `hashCode()` for other collection structures to work properly.

P.S. You should probably be using `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`. From [the docs for `Vector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html):

> If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use `ArrayList` in place of `Vector`.

Even when a thread-safe implementation is needed, you are usually better off providing your own synchronization. The single-function-call synchronization offered by `Vector` is usually at the wrong granularity.

Comment: And even if it happens to be at the appropriate granularity, you can simply use `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList())`.

Comment: @JBNizet - Good point. But `new Vector()` seems simpler than all of that.

Comment: It's simpler, but it hides the intention. `Collections.synchronizedList()` makes it clear that what is wanted is a synchronized list. `new Vector()` doesn't say anything like that (and is not coherent with `Collections.synchronizedSet()`, for which there is no equivalent `new OldSynchronizedSet()`).

Comment: @JBNizet - Another good point. I hadn't thought about the self-documenting aspect. I guess I'd also use the more elaborate code, now that you point it out.